# Dojo : Cannot read property 'h' of undefined on AccordionContainer.js?

Tags: javascript, dojo, accordion

I am getting an error like this when I created Two accordion containers dynamically under an accordion container.

The error will not happens when I created any of these single accordion container instead of create both together.

> Error :
>
> **Cannot read property 'h' of undefined on AccordionContainer.js**

I have temporarily fix the problem by adding these lines to tool kit file, 
dojo-toolkit\dijit\layout\AccordionContainer.js

```
Line 91: + if(this._contentBox) 
Line 92:    this._verticalSpace=_34.h-_35-_2f.h-_30.h-_32.h-_33.h-_2d._buttonWidget.getTitleHeight(); 
Line 93: + if(this._contentBox) 
Line 94:    this._containerContentBox={h:this._verticalSpace,w:this._contentBox.w-_2f.w-_30.w-_32.w- _33.w};
```

**Accordion Widget creation code structure is**

```
define("test/project", [ 
        "dojo/_base/declare", 
        "dijit/_Widget", 
        "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer"], 
    function(declare, _Widget, AccordionContainer) { 
        return declare([_Widget],{ 
                         postCreate: function() { 
                                var new_acc = new AccordionContainer({ 
                                        id: "new_acc", 
                                        title: "Approval ("+this.count+")" 
                                }); 

                               this.parentId.addChild(new_acc); 
                        } 
        });     
});
```

Any idea to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Reported as issue https://github.com/dojo/dojo/issues/428

Answer (score 4):

i am facing the same issue but i figured it out.when you try to create another child in accordion after aContainer.startup(); method, it will generate the same error message. startup method start the accordion and it will apply height & width to that accordion dynamically, if your again creating a child to it after accordion is created already it will throw an error "Cannot read property 'h' of undefined on AccordionContainer.js"

```
      aContainer = new AccordionContainer({ style: "height: 300px" },acdic);
        aContainer.addChild(new ContentPane({
            title: "This is a content pane",
            content: "Hi!"
        }));

        aContainer.addChild(new ContentPane({
            title: "This is as well",
            content: "Hi how are you?",
            id: "pane1"
        }));
        aContainer.startup();            
        aContainer.addChild(new ContentPane({
            title: "This too",
            content: "Hello im fine.. thnx"
        }));
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this problem is to **first** add the children to the AccordianContainer and **then** add the AccordianContainer to the parent.